# Is this an Apple tree in my new yard?

Tags: identification, trees, apples

Is this an Apple tree in my new yard??
I would like to know what kind of tree this is.

[image]

Comment: I don't think its apple - that distinctive bark's all wrong for apple, but the trouble is, I'm not sure what else it could be, other than maybe an ornamental cherry. Can you post another photo from farther back so we can see the growth habit please?

Answer (score 5):

This is clearly not an apple tree! I have many apple tree and flowers will not come with a stem that large.

It is from the [Prunus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus) genus - probably ornamental, given its beautiful flowers.

Comment: I would put my bets in a cherry tree (Prunus avium): mainly for the leaves, then a grey trunk (which is also common on apple), but also for the "white spot" on the branch

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is an apple; Malus pumila.  This is not the bark I know  but after a  search, I guess it is possible.  The flowers and the stem you show are apple.  What I'd like to see is the rest of the tree to include the crown  and shape of the tree.  a close up of the leaves but from here sure looks like apple leaves.  Those flowers are definitely apple.  How weird.  Send more pictures so that we can see the health of this tree and be able to give you suggestions so that you might be able to get fruit.  How did you think of apple, by the way?  There will be others to answer this question, are you able to send more pictures being so new?

Comment: The leaves say *prunus*, not *malus* and the flowers as well. Both are too delicate for malus.

Comment: Whoa, for real?  I'll go check again.  Thanks Stephie...do an answer.  That bark threw me, the grey bark.  But the flowers sure look like malus.  I love this.  I love being wrong 'cause guess what?  I learn THAT wrong thing quite clearly.  Genius, Stephie!!  Grins!!

Comment: definitely a cherry!